# change the template of the message that arrives via e-mail

Tags: javascript, email, server, angular7, angular7-router

I ask about the  messages that arrive via email
I  if I want to change the template of the message that arrives via e-mail 
,Where do I change the template from server or code?

Comment: Emails get sent out by the server, so that's where the template will be stored. Without more details it's impossible to get more specific though.

Comment: The question is too broad. There are a lot of possible answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the sender side, you may set a template or set up emails in the format needed for sending out.

Answer (score 1):

From code.
You can add a component to your app to build template easely : https://em.wlocalhost.org/?utm_source=category_description&utm_medium=forum